# I need help sorting out an issue subprocess call function

Tags: python

I am trying to create a password cracker for a challenge on picoCTF (specifically PW Crack 4) that is written in python. My exact problem is as follows: Their is a file python file (called level4.py) which when ran asks for the correct password and if the correct password is given then a flag will be presented. Their is a list that needs to be ran, this list can be found inside the file on the picoCTF challenge (that is found above) called level4.py, this list contains possible passwords. Their needs to be a code written that runs the file level4.py and tries every password in this list.

pos_pw_list = ["158f", "1655", "d21e", "4966", "ed69", "1010", "dded", "844c", "40ab", "a948", "156c", "ab7f", "4a5f", "e38c", "ba12", "f7fd", "d780", "4f4d", "5ba1", "96c5", "55b9", "8a67", "d32b", "aa7a", "514b", "e4e1", "1230", "cd19", "d6dd", "b01f", "fd2f", "7587", "86c2", "d7b8", "55a2", "b77c", "7ffe", "4420", "e0ee", "d8fb", "d748", "b0fe", "2a37", "a638", "52db", "51b7", "5526", "40ed", "5356", "6ad4", "2ddd", "177d", "84ae", "cf88", "97a3", "17ad", "7124", "eff2", "e373", "c974", "7689", "b8b2", "e899", "d042", "47d9", "cca9", "ab2a", "de77", "4654", "9ecb", "ab6e", "bb8e", "b76b", "d661", "63f8", "7095", "567e", "b837", "2b80", "ad4f", "c514", "ffa4", "fc37", "7254", "b48b", "d38b", "a02b", "ec6c", "eacc", "8b70", "b03e", "1b36", "81ff", "77e4", "dbe6", "59d9", "fd6a", "5653", "8b95", "d0e5"]

from subprocess import call

def hi_py(x):
call(["python", "level4.py"])
print(x)

def loop():
for x in range(0, 100):
hi_py(str(pos_pw_list[x]))

loop()

This is the code that I am trying to run. The problem that I run into is that the print(x) part of the code does not print inside the bit when the file level4.py is ran and asks for a password it prints after something is entered by the user. This may be a problem with the call function but I don't know what to do instead. This image shows the picture version of what I tried to explain above: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/yrFDE.png)

Comment: This is your job to find out, you should not ask competition questions on stack overflow. If you don't know how to answer the question you should practice more and join the next one.

Comment: This is my way of finding out. I cant 'just practice more' as if their is direct gaps in my knowledge that I have already tried to fill in other ways than practicing, practicing more will not help me. It will just leave a gap in my knowledge which I am now trying to fill in here. So if you could help that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is not a good Idea to ask the competition question for learning either, Instead you can set up challenges for yourself, or just google picoCTF practice! [This Medium article](https://vonhoenec.medium.com/picogym-practice-challenges-general-skills-part-1-b36871b08264) can also be a good starting point.

Comment: Already tried that. This is why I asked the question usually I don't ask questions about picoCTF on here (as you can see it is my first post). But seeming I couldn't find answers anywhere else, like I had already stated previously, I decided to ask a question on here. So if you could help that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sadly I don't have any recommendations for that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `subprocess.Popen` to write the input properly and read the output of the script:

```
process = Popen(["python", "level4.py"], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, text=True)
output, _ = process.communicate(input=x)
```

At the current point in time you aren't actually giving an input when calling the file, but just printing the password.
After calling `process.comunicate` and giving the input you can print out the output as follows:

```
print(f"Output for password {x}: {output.strip()}")
```

Please remember that you probably aren't learning much from just asking for answers on StackOverflow and that it is potentially unfair to other participants.

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply I will adjust my code accordingly and let you know how I get on. I do understand your concerns but seeming as this is my only option to learning this content I deem it to be applicable. Thank you again for your help.

Comment: Thanks for your help I have got the CTF done. I will make sure to follow up with some more research into Popen and subsequently expand my knowledge on this topic. Once again thank you very much.

Comment: Why are you using subprocesses for this? level4.py contains everything you need to know.

Comment: I am aware of the other ways to solve this CTF. I wanted to solve it the way my question describes as that password cracker will now work for many other applications.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at level4.py you'll see that all the functionality is laid bare. There's no good reason for using subprocesses.

Open level4.py and delete or comment out line 39 then, in a new .py file:

```
import level4

for pw in level4.pos_pw_list:
    if level4.hash_pw(pw) == level4.correct_pw_hash:
        print(level4.str_xor(level4.flag_enc.decode(), pw))
        break
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment I have already solved it using subproceses and I am aware of the other ways to solve this CTF. I wanted to solve it the way my question describes as that password cracker will now work for many other applications.